# express how to make the route catch prefix

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am using node with express. I have the following route:

```
app.get('/facebook/auth/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/auth-failure' }, users.authSuccess));
```

How do I make this route match to:

```
http://localhost:3000/facebook/auth/callback?error_code=2102&error_message=User+is+not+a+test+user+owned+by+the+application#_=_
```

(for some unknown reasons this route doesn't catch the url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex

```
app.get('/facebook/auth/callback?*',passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/auth-failure' }, users.authSuccess));
```